# Why does the background color of a selected radio button overlap with the hover state one?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm working on some form elements, and I have this radio button that, when hovered, turns the background gray; when selected, the background turns to green.

I already wrote the CSS code and it does exactly what I want. But the CSS syntax confused me.

```css
   .opt-container:hover .new-button, .opt-container:hover .button-label {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    .opt-container input:checked ~ .new-button, .opt-container input:checked ~ .button-label {
     background-color: #7EE29E;
    }
```

```html
<label class="radio-label">
  <div class="opt-container">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio-button" value="m" checked="checked">
    <span class="new-button"></span>
    <div class="button-label">
      Male
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label class="radio-label">
  <div class="opt-container">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio-button" value="f">
    <span class="new-button"></span>
    <div class="button-label">
      Female
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

The code works. When hovering new-button (replacing default radio button) the button-label (label) will have a background-color of gray. When clicked it turns to green.

With `.opt-container` as the parent element (the box containing new-button & button-label).

I'm a bit confused on how to translate the code, especially the "selected  state".

Example: if I erase the `opt-container` from the selected state, the box will turn gray again when I put my cursor above it (but when the cursor not hovers above it, it still green).

Why does it overlap with the hover code?

Comment: can you share the HTML also  ? and what is there that's confusing you ? there are some styles being applied to the label and button when changing the state of the input ( hover or checked )

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jodranata/full/wvwJEGd

Comment: ok, so...which part does confuse you ?

Comment: Here's the when the code is running. 
I'm a bit confused with the css syntax, when hover and checked are applied.

Why do I need to put ~.opt-container~ as the parent element before input(on checked syntax)? if not, the box will turn to gray again when the cursor hovers above it, even after I checked the input.

Comment: Hi, we need to see the HTML in the question itself, please. A link to CodePen on its own is insufficient (e.g. the link could die, you could update your code, CodePen could go down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I just copy-pasted your code ( HTML and CSS ).

Explanation

```
.opt-container:hover .new-button,
.opt-container:hover .button-label {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

THis code is pretty straight forward. When the `opt-container` div is hovered, the background of the `.button-label` and the `button-label` is being changed to a grey color ( black color with 0.5 opacity )

```
.opt-container input:checked~.new-button,
.opt-container input:checked~.button-label {
    background-color: #7EE29E;
 }
```

The input has the checked state when it or it's label is clicked. Being inside a `<label>` element, when clicking anywhere inside that `label` element, the input will get the `checked` state.

So the above code means when the input is checked, change the button and the label background color to `7EE29E` = some shade of green. The `~` is used to select all siblings that come after an element. Adjacent ( right after ) or not. That's why it's called general siblings selector.

So in the first line it would've been more specific to use `+` the adjacent sibling selector because `new-button` is right after `input`. But using `~` is not a mistake and also it's needed in the second line because `button-label` is a sibling but not an adjacent sibling of `input` so you can select it only with `~`.

You don't need to use `.opt-container` in this specific case because i don't see any other labels or inputs in your HTML structure. It's just about CSS specificity in this case.
See more here -> [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Let me know in the comments if you have any more questions.

```css
.opt-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80%;
  left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.opt-container input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-label {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 660px;
  left: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.radio-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.opt-container:hover .new-button,
.opt-container:hover .button-label {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.opt-container input:checked~.new-button,
.opt-container input:checked~.button-label {
  background-color: #7EE29E;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-label">
  <div class="opt-container">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio-button" value="m" checked="checked">
    <span class="new-button"></span>
    <div class="button-label">
      Male
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label class="radio-label">
  <div class="opt-container">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio-button" value="f">
    <span class="new-button"></span>
    <div class="button-label">
      Female
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: I tried deleting the opt-container from the css checked state. It'll still turn green when it's checked, but when I hover my cursor, it'll turns to gray again(if I move the cursor away, the box is green). Only by putting the opt-container before input checked, it'll stay green. Why is that?

Comment: @Jodranata As i told you. It's about CSS selector specificity. The `.opt-container:hover .new-button,` is more specific than `input:checked ~ new.button` and that's why the hover gray  color is placed above the green. Please read that link about css specificity.

Comment: Yes I just read about it, thanks for the link. as beginner, there's still many basic CSS rules that I need to learn. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jodranata no problem. If you have any more questions, please ask. Cheers ! :D